# Finding the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y = x\,\text{arctanh}(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We just learnt Leibniz General rule and my professor gave us this question, I did solve it but I don't know if I got the right answer. I tried testing it finding the $7^{th}$ derivative and comparing my answer to derivative-calculator.net's answer and it said they weren't equivalent. This is what I did.
$\DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{arctanh}$

First: $\because \arctanh x = \frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) \implies y = \frac{1}{2}x\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$

I then give $x$ the name $v$ and $\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ the name $u$ and apply Leibniz rule as follows:
$$(uv)^n(x)=\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}u^{(n-k)}v^{(k)}(x)$$ 
Which in this case $y^{(n)} = {^n}C_0u^{(n)}v^{(0)} + {^n}C_1u^{(n-1)}v^{(1)}$

Then I separately found the $n^{th}$ derivative for $u$ which evaluated to 
$u^{(n)} = (n-2)!(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n}} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^n})$ and substituted $n$ for $n-1$ to find $u^{(n-1)}$ so I won't write it here
then I substituted $u^{(n)}, u^{(n-1)}, v^{(0)}, v^{(1)}$ in $y^{(n)} = u^{(n)}v^{(0)} + nu^{(n-1)}v^{(1)}$

the final, simplest form I reached was

$$(n-2)![(xn-x)(\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n}} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^n})+n(\frac{(-1)^{n-2}}{(1+x)^{n-1}}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n-1}})]$$

As I said, I tried testing it for the $7^{th}$ derivative and compared my result to the calculator's result and it failed, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. It was just a common human error while calculating $u^{(n)}$.

Let $u(x) = \ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) = \ln(1+x) - \ln(1-x)$. Then for $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$
$$\begin{split}
u^{(n+1)}(x) &= \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left[ \frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{1}{1-x} \right] \\
&= (-1)^n\frac{n!}{(1+x)^{n+1}} + \frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}} \\
&= n! \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{(1+x)^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}} \right).
\end{split}$$